# Not able to run java EE project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I have an existing java (EE) project, which I am trying to run from eclipse. I have imported that project in eclipse and added the tomcat7 server. But when I am running the project, it is giving spring error as

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'seoDestinationsDataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/fn-landing-persistence-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'seodestinations.db.driverClassName' in string value "${seodestinations.db.driverClassName}"
```

Please find below snapshot of error.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPLNj.png)

What is the step i am missing. Please advise. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please, if you think it's relevant to your question, paste the error as text inside the question.

Comment: I have updated the question